# Creating lots of Ofstream writer pointers for lots of files in for loop

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, heap-memory, ostream

I am trying to create lots of (around 57000) ofstream pointers to specific files, So whenever I receive data, I can write it in specific file.

After 1021 pointers the pointers to the files become corrupt.
Here is sample code and its log:

```
#include <iostream>     // std::cout, std::ios
#include <sstream>      // std::stringstream
#include <fstream>
#include <string>


int main () {


    int count = 0;
    for (int i =0; i<60000; i++)
    {
        count++ ;
        std::string filename = "abc" + std::to_string(i) + "_data" ;
        std::ofstream* abc = new std::ofstream( filename.c_str(), std::ios::app );;
        std::cout << "isGood->" << abc->good() <<",count=" << count << ",filname="<< filename << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output Log of the above code:

```
...
...
isGood->1,count=1011,filname=abc1010_data
isGood->1,count=1012,filname=abc1011_data
isGood->1,count=1013,filname=abc1012_data
isGood->1,count=1014,filname=abc1013_data
isGood->1,count=1015,filname=abc1014_data
isGood->1,count=1016,filname=abc1015_data
isGood->1,count=1017,filname=abc1016_data
isGood->1,count=1018,filname=abc1017_data
isGood->1,count=1019,filname=abc1018_data
isGood->1,count=1020,filname=abc1019_data
isGood->1,count=1021,filname=abc1020_data
isGood->0,count=1022,filname=abc1021_data
isGood->0,count=1023,filname=abc1022_data
isGood->0,count=1024,filname=abc1023_data
isGood->0,count=1025,filname=abc1024_data
isGood->0,count=1026,filname=abc1025_data
isGood->0,count=1027,filname=abc1026_data
isGood->0,count=1028,filname=abc1027_data
...
...
```

The Zero after isGood is the problem, it represent that file is not present or can't be written.

Thanks.

Comment: This sounds like you want to have 57,000 files open at the same time? Is that what you’re saying?

Comment: `New` without a `Delete` causes memory leak.

Comment: Tom Zych : Yes !

Comment: What is the question ? the specified limit from OS/standard ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure your OS limit is 1024, and you're hitting it with the help of stdin, stdout and stderr.

Comment: It might be possible in theory but it sounds like it would place a lot of strain on the OS at best …

Comment: Quentin OS limit of what ?

Comment: Limit of open files.

Comment: _"whenever I receive data, I can write it in specific file."_ And why do you (think you) need all of these files always to be open at all times, rather than just when they need to be written to? Consider explaining *what* you're trying to do, not *how*; this may be an X/Y question.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?, all you are checking is the file is good or not and the count - Perhaps after you check that blose the file and delete the pointer. Work on the files later on a case by case basis?

Comment: So?  If you know there is a memory leak, fix it.  And you are better off closing each file immediately after append.  So many open files will slow the OS not just for your application, for for all applications running on the machine.

Comment: I will store these pointers in a map, need them later.

Comment: Again, why do you think you need that? Can't you just store the filenames for later, and only have them open for as long as they actually need to be open? Bottom line, it's very likely that no OS is going to let you do this, and it would be a code smell even if it did, so rethink your design.

Comment: All OSes have a hard limit on the number of files that can be open at the same time. Your code is not anywhere close to being fit for production.

Comment: Well Okay, for now I have done changes: I delete the pointer. then I again create the pointer at run time, earlier I wanted to create all pointers for all files at one go, but Now I am creating deleting.